# Install npm and grunt locally

Tags: npm, gruntjs

is it possible to install `npm`, `grunt-cli` and `grunt` locally only in the main folder of my website project?
If yes, how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Would something like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nodeenv/ help?

Comment: Grunt - yes, npm & grunt-cli - no, those only work as globals.

Comment: @Tyler, yes I think that it could be useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes. `nvm` is a node version manager - you can install multiple versions of node/npm, each with their own boxed global packages.
You can then switch between them as you like.

documentation and source: [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)